# Haskell : not getting this with IO [FilePath]

Tags: haskell, io

Working through tutorials etc. in ghci - so far so good. I'm so completely missing something though : my function builds an `IO [FilePath]` "thing". In ghci it comes out like this:

`["xml","velocity.log.1","velocity.log"]`  (list truncated for brevity)

I see that the function is doing what I want. Next step is I want to "print" that out myself.

Nothing I do lets me print the result. I don't want to perpetuate my Java/C#/Python habits in Haskell - no point in that. I believe there's a good reason for Haskell doing things differently, but I can't see how to get the (limited) value out of this function.

```
module Main (
    main
) where

import RecursiveContents

main = do putStrLn "this"
          getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"
```

This works. But what if I want main to print the result of `getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"` ?

In ghci I can just type/paste `getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"` and the stuff spews out - what do I have to do to print it myself?

If I do :

`let xyz = getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"` in ghci, the only thing I can do with `xyz` is type:
`xyz <enter>` and see the result.

I cannot do head, tail, etc. etc.. I know that `IO [FilePath]` is something special and not a the same as array or list `[a]` - but nothing I do is helping me to understand getting past this.

I must be missing something - something I can't find in [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com), or [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org). Am I not rtfm-ing in the right place?

Any feedback or dope-slaps appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the results of an IO action (i.e. to run the action) you *bind* the results of the `IO` computation to a variable:

Assuming:

```
getRecursiveContents :: FilePath -> IO String
```

Then you can just print the result:

```
main = do str <- getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"
          print str
```

Obviously this is just an example, but when the function really is just two lines people don't usually use `do` notation and avoid explicitly naming the intermediate variable of `str`:

```
main = getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir" >>= print
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - I was missing the all-important "<-"

Answer (score 5):

Use `<-` in the do-notation to get to the `[FilePath]`. You can then manipulate it with any list functions, as long as you end up with some `IO` action.

```
main = do putStrLn "this"
          contents <- getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"
          print contents
```

Alternatively, you can use `>>=` to feed the output of one `IO` action into another. It's the same thing, just written differently.

```
main = do putStrLn "this"
          getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir" >>= print
```

For a more thorough explanation, see the I/O chapters of

- [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output)
- [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io.html)

---

The reason why it works in GHCi, is that when GHCi has evaluated your expression, it looks at the type. If it's `IO a`, it will run the action and display the result automatically, while in a real program you have to do this yourself. See the [GHC user's guide](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.3/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html).

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - I was missing the all-important "<-"

Comment: @user... you'll notice that one of these doesn't actually use a `<-`

Answer (score 4):

You can bind values in do blocks. This is also the place where you can apply pure functions (like show, tail and so on):

```
main = do putStrLn "this"
          x <- getRecursiveContents "/home/xyz/myDir"
          putStrLn (show x)
```

If the foo is of type IO a then you need something like do and x <- foo to get the value.

Consult any monad tutorial for more info.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply - I was missing the all-important "<-"